# Are there any recipes or diagrams in Smuggler Caches or Spoils of War?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am in the final stage of the Witcher 3, and trying to collect all Alchemy recipes and available Diagrams, especially for rare swords.

I cleared most of the question marks in Skellige, except those in water which are always either a Smuggler Cache, or Spoils of War. I just hate fighting tons of sirens, risking losing the ship, wasting ~10 minutes of real time just to clear single location. After two of those, decided to ask first.

So the question is: are there any alchemy recipes or diagrams in Smuggler Caches or Spoils of War locations? If there are, I'll swallow the frog and clear them all as well, but  if it's just useless loot I'll pass, I got way more money than I need anyway. (In the game. ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most recipes and diagrams appear randomly so you may find them in these locations but I am pretty certain there aren't any which only appear in the sea in Skellige.

I recently finished a play through and found all the Alchemy recipes without searching these locations.

There are some small quests hidden away on some of the smaller Skellige islands, including one of the most powerful creatures in the game (DLC excluded) so you might want to look around.

Comment: Thanks, sure about "appear randomly"? Or just guessing? Actually I didn't really check if I got all recipes, assumed I haven't yet. I saw the creature, fought it bravely, and died horribly. (one hit kill. :))

Comment: Well I have done six playthroughs now and recipes don't appear in the same place each time. I think some chests have a better chance that others but there doesn't seem to be any discernible pattern of what turns up when or where. On one playthrough I did do every last place in Skellige and I don't remember getting anything interesting.